# Neo4j Lucene full-text search and keyword extraction from the text

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher, full-text-search, apoc

I have Neo4j `FULLTEXT INDEX` with ~60k records (keywords). This is my keyword vocabulary.  I need to extract all possible keywords (which are present in this index) from the different input texts. Is this possible to implement with Neo4j, Cypher, APOC ?

**UPDATED**

For example there is a text:

```
Looking for Apache Spark expert to coach me on the core concepts of optimizing the parallelism of Spark using Scala and OpenAcc programming model.

The mentor must have comprehensive hands-on knowledge of Big Data analytics in large scale of data  (especially Spark and GPU programming) to design the software tool with sample data analysis using Scala language and OpenAcc directives.
```

In the Neo4j database with `FULLTEXT INDEX` I have the following keywords:

```
apache-spark
scala
gpu
```

I need to extract from the text above

```
Apache Spark
Scala
GPU
```

Comment: Can you detail a bit the question ? I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for especially `from the different input texts.` , maybe add an example with expected result ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen thanks for your answer. I have updated the question with an example

Answer (score 1):

So, generally using an FT index is for the opposite use case, storing the texts in the index and matching for keywords, nevertheless :

**Poor Man Solution**

Query the index with your text. For eg, given the following setup

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex('Keyword', ['Keyword'], ['value'])
```

```
CREATE (n:Keyword {value: 'apache-spark'})
CREATE (n:Keyword {value: 'gpu'})
CREATE (n:Keyword {value: 'scala'})
```

Use your text as search query

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('Keyword', 'Looking for Apache Spark expert to coach me on the core concepts of optimizing the parallelism of Spark using Scala and OpenAcc programming model.

The mentor must have comprehensive hands-on knowledge of Big Data analytics in large scale of data  (especially Spark and GPU programming) to design the software tool with sample data analysis using Scala language and OpenAcc directives. ')
```

Since a lucene query will by default use all tokens of the text with an `OR` operator, it will work

Result :

```
╒════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╕
│"node"                  │"score"            │
╞════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│{"value":"apache-spark"}│1.480496883392334  │
├────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│{"value":"scala"}       │0.9932447671890259 │
├────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│{"value":"gpu"}         │0.49662238359451294│
└────────────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Limitations :

This is with an `OR` operator, so while here it works you need to know that when you index the keywords, a keyword like `apache-spark` will actually produce two tokens in the index, namely `apache` and `spark`, so this would be returned as well if your text would contain `Apache Age`.

**Alternative solution**

Do the other way around, the process would be :

1. create an FTS index for the input texts
2. store temporarily the input text into a node
3. start from the keywords, clean them and build up lucene queries dynamically from them
4. query the FTS index for input texts
5. Delete the text node

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex('Text', ['Text'], ['text'])
```

```
WITH 'Looking for Apache Spark expert to coach me on the core concepts of optimizing the parallelism of Spark using Scala and OpenAcc programming model.

The mentor must have comprehensive hands-on knowledge of Big Data analytics in large scale of data  (especially Spark and GPU programming) to design the software tool with sample data analysis using Scala language and OpenAcc directives. '
AS text
CREATE (n:Text {text: text})
```

```
MATCH (n:Keyword)
// remove non alpha numeric characters
WITH n, apoc.text.regreplace(n.value, '[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]', ' ') AS clean
WITH n, split(clean, ' ') AS tokens
// build up an FTS query for doing an `AND` operator
WITH n, '(' + apoc.text.join(tokens, ' AND ') + ')' AS query
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('Text', query)
YIELD node, score
// make sure to return the keyword node so we know how it did match
RETURN n, node,sum(score)
```

This will be the lucene queries produced

```
╒════════════════════╕
│"query"             │
╞════════════════════╡
│"(apache AND spark)"│
├────────────────────┤
│"(gpu)"             │
├────────────────────┤
│"(scala)"           │
├────────────────────┤
│"(apache AND age)"  │
└────────────────────┘
```

```
MATCH (n:Text) DELETE n
```

Result

```
╒════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╕
│"n"                     │"node"                                                                │"sum(score)"       │
╞════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│{"value":"apache-spark"}│{"text":"Looking for Apache Spark expert to coach me on the core conce│0.33785906434059143│
│                        │pts of optimizing the parallelism of Spark using Scala and OpenAcc pro│                   │
│                        │gramming model.\n
The mentor must have comprehensive hands-on knowledg│                   │
│                        │e of Big Data analytics in large scale of data  (especially Spark and │                   │
│                        │GPU programming) to design the software tool with sample data analysis│                   │
│                        │ using Scala language and OpenAcc directives. "}                      │                   │
├────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│{"value":"gpu"}         │{"text":"Looking for Apache Spark expert to coach me on the core conce│0.13164746761322021│
│                        │pts of optimizing the parallelism of Spark using Scala and OpenAcc pro│                   │
│                        │gramming model.\n
The mentor must have comprehensive hands-on knowledg│                   │
│                        │e of Big Data analytics in large scale of data  (especially Spark and │                   │
│                        │GPU programming) to design the software tool with sample data analysis│                   │
│                        │ using Scala language and OpenAcc directives. "}                      │                   │
├────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│{"value":"scala"}       │{"text":"Looking for Apache Spark expert to coach me on the core conce│0.18063414096832275│
│                        │pts of optimizing the parallelism of Spark using Scala and OpenAcc pro│                   │
│                        │gramming model.\n
```

**Summary**

There is in my opinion no real bullet proof solution really

Comment: Thank you very much! I need a time to test it.

Comment: @alexanoid any luck at testing it ?

Comment: I tested the solution #1 - it produces a lot of false positive keywords. I'm still going to test the solution #2

Comment: I really apologize for the late response (had to switch to other important task) Now I test the solution #2. Right now on my test set it fails with the following error `'Failed to invoke procedure db.index.fulltext.queryNodes: Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Encountered " <AND> "AND "" at line 1, column 15.'`

Comment: Also I may have the following keywords, like `c++` or `.net` so I don't need to clean all of that `[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]` but maybe escape special Lucene characters? Also I have the keywords in non English languages. Could you please help to rewrite this query in order to support all of that?

Comment: And one more case - sometimes I may see the following `tokens`  - `["", "", "", "", "", ""]` which leads to the following Lucene query - `AND AND AND AND AND`